# Linq query return exception in production mode

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a query like this in my c# code windows form application:

```
var repeatedDesign = ProjectHistoryModel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DesignName.Equals(designName) && x.ProjectName.Equals(projectName));
```

I already tested in local and it works correctly, for some reason when I publish it, this query returns null exception. Someone have an idea what can be the problem with this linq query? Regards

Comment: There are three things in that statement that can possibly be `null`. How are we to know which one of them it is? Consider breaking that statement up so that's it's easier to debug and log.

Comment: Are you running against the same data(base) locally vs. published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use == instead of Equals().

Comment: wtf? can you explain me why in local it works and in production dont?

Comment: When the property is null, `.Equals()` can not be called on it

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is `x.DesignName` or `x.ProjectName` is Null so its `.Equals()` cannot be called. The first answer should be a good suggestion, use `==` instead of `.Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code instead :

This Code is safe :

```
var repeatedDesign = ProjectHistoryModel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DesignName == designName && x.ProjectName == projectName);
```

or

```
if (designName == null) return;
if (projectName == null) return;
var repeatedDesign = ProjectHistoryModel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DesignName.Equals(designName) && x.ProjectName.Equals(projectName));
```